# ASP.NET WebAPI passing empty string in urlencoded body as null

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, urlencode

I have a simple ApiController

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int orderid, [FromBody] Order order)
{
    // Do something useful with order.Notes here
}
```

and a class (the actual class contains several more properties)

```
public class Order
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and wish to handle PUT requests of the following type

```
PUT http://localhost/api/orders/{orderid}
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

notes=sometext
```

Everything works fine, but empty values are passed as null

```
notes=blah            // passes blah
notes=                // Passes null
someothervalue=blah   // Passes null
```

Is it possible to have ApiController distinguish between empty values and missing values?

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried annotating the property with DisplayFormatAttribute, like,

```
public class Order
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This worked as perfectly. Rembember to add a reference to Assembly:  **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll)** and import the namespace. For full documentation see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The root of this comes from the `ReplaceEmptyStringWithNull` that calls `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

To fix this across your entire WebAPI project, you need to swap out the `ModelMetadataProvider` with one that sets the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` to `false`

See [Set default for DisplayFormatAttribute.ConvertEmptyStringToNull to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308201/set-default-for-displayformatattribute-convertemptystringtonull-to-false/36558116#36558116)

This was actually "fixed" in v6 - see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3593