# pass value as empty string to WEb API from typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass an empty string to C# web api from javascript.
But when i pass empty string from typescript i get null in the webapi parameter.
How to pass empty string?

here is my client web api call:

```
public ChangePassword(username: string, oldPassword: string, newPassword: string) {
    const oldPwd = (oldPassword === null || oldPassword === undefined) ? '' : oldPassword;
    const newPwd = (newPassword === null || newPassword === undefined) ? '' : newPassword;

    const endPointUrl: string = this.webApi.EndPoint + '/Authentication/ChangePassword';
    const parameters = new HttpParams()
        .set('username', username)
        .set('oldPassword', oldPwd)
        .set('newPassword', newPwd);
    return this.httpClient.post(endPointUrl, '', { params: parameters });
}
```

And my web api is

```
[HttpPost]
    public void ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        WebServiceFault fault = _securityManager.ChangePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword);
        if (fault == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        throw WebApiServiceFaultHelper.CreateFaultException(fault);
    }
```

When i pass null as parameter for old and new password to the `ChangePassword()` method i get the string as null in the web api method insted of getting an empty string.

Comment: There are a few details that Suren has pointed out below, that I would agree with. I'm going to be the elephant in the room and ask: What *exactly* is your use case for passing an empty string to your controller? Is doing a `string.IsNullOrEmpty` check not enough? or do you need to use both `null` and `""` cases in your code?

Comment: null and " " have different meaning. null defines that the user did not call the api properly and " " defines that the user wants to set empty password.

Comment: It's reasonable enough that you have different use cases for them. What I can't make head or tails of, is that you're allowing users to set an empty password..? If you ask me, that's just bad design. Is there any reason *why* you need to let your users set empty passwords?

Comment: Either way, in terms of differentiating between `string.Empty` and `null` when deserializing your values, would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14610739/6240567) help?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a *post* request, so consider to pass data via *body* as the second argument, not as query params.

```
public ChangePassword(username: string, oldPassword: string, newPassword: string) {
    const oldPwd = (oldPassword === null || oldPassword === undefined) ? '' : oldPassword;
    const newPwd = (newPassword === null || newPassword === undefined) ? '' : newPassword;

    const endPointUrl: string = this.webApi.EndPoint + '/Authentication/ChangePassword';

    return this.httpClient.post(endPointUrl, { username, oldPwd, newPwd });
}
```

And get in the API using `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public void ChangePassword([FromBody]string userName, [FromBody]string oldPassword, [FromBody]string newPassword)
{
    WebServiceFault fault = _securityManager.ChangePassword(userName, oldPassword, newPassword);
    if (fault == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    throw WebApiServiceFaultHelper.CreateFaultException(fault);
}
```

Also it will better to have a model which describes the change password model and get the data as a model, not as separate parameters. Something like

```
[HttpPost]
public void ChangePassword([FromBody]ChangePasswordModel model)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you know any way to attempt on the core problem. i.e, passing an empty string to web api method?

Comment: If you pass an empty string, it will reached as an empty string.

Comment: Yes thats the main problem. if you observe in the client ChangePassword method if the string is null or undefined i pass empty string. Still the web api received null.

Comment: Do you get any data in the API ?

Comment: I get it as null.

Comment: If you pass some string, do you get it?

Comment: Yes, I do get it. I have only problem with not able to pass empty string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168527/discussion-between-nomesh-gajare-and-suren-srapyan).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing as separate parameters use a model as below,

```
public class ChangePasswordModel 
{
     [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
     public string userName { get; set; }
     [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
     public string oldPassword { get; set; }
     [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
     public string newPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Use it as,

```
[HttpPost]
public void ChangePassword([FromBody]ChangePasswordModel model)
```

[DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute on the property of your model class will do the thing what you want.